# Can multi-threads call a global function?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

I am working on an OJ(back end) . In my evaluator I create 3 threads which then evaluate
submissions independently.The function for the threads is `process_submission` this
function in turn calls global functions `Compile` and `Execute`.
My doubt is when one thread runs and it in turn calls `Compile` or `Execute` and then it pre-empts does it start from the same point in the function `Compile` or `Execute` when it is loaded back or do I have to do everything concerning a thread in its function `process_submission`.

PS: sorry for my poor usage of terms , please tell me if something is not correct.

Comment: What language are you using?  What is an OJ?  Googling "OJ back end" just leads to articles about OJ Simpson.

Comment: Anyway, in most languages, as long as you're not utilizing mutable global state data, you shouldn't need any synchronization or locking.

Comment: Online judge i am using python 2.7

Comment: what is mutable global data state can you elaborate more, Compile function creates executable of a program and stores it in tmp.out and then execute function is passed a executable which is then run by it and output of the executable is compared with standard output

Comment: mutable global state is anything that is accessed by multiple threads and can be modified by at least one of them.  In this case a file called tmp.out definitely qualifies.  If two threads are executing Compile at the same time, one of them will acquire a lock on tmp.out allowing it to write to it.  The other one will probably block while waiting for the file to become available. When the first Compile finishes, the file will probably be closed, and by the time Execute runs, it may or may not have been overwritten by the other thread's Compile function.

Comment: @bcrist so to avoid overwriting I have to use acquire and release lock while calling execute and compile function from a thread, will it solve this problem ??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32620/discussion-between-sasha-sami-and-bcrist)